# SQL - Which data type represents percentages well?

Tags: sql

In SQL I am looking at [decimal and float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx).  Float says it is an approximation.  I need to store percentages.  They don't have to be very large or small.  Some examples are

```
60.2

40
```

Which data type should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
decimal(x,y)
```

x is the total number of digits you want to be able to represent

y is the total number of digits after the decimal point that you want to be able to represent

Comment: +1 - He probably wants something like `(8,5)` to allow up to 100

Comment: (8,5) would allow him to enter 100.99999, whereas in his question he only references needing one place after the decimal, so wouldn't he be better served by (4,1) or even (3,1)?

Comment: He doesn't really specify what he needs - just a way to efficiently store percentages. How much precision he desires can be defined as he wishes.

Comment: The client hasn't specified exactly how precise we should be.  This type gives me the flexibility I need to make changes if necessary.  Thanks, this is a great answer.